# openshift Imagestream is not resolved as expected

Tags: openshift, imagestream

Playing around  with the Openshift-Sandbox I stuck in a (somehow) trivial problem.
I build an image with a build-configuration and push it to ImageStreamTag:

```
(buildconfig)
(....)
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'goedel-db-connector:latest'
(....)
```

This works fine and the Image seems to be there

```
oc get is/goedel-db-connector 
NAME                  IMAGE REPOSITORY                                                                                                       TAGS     UPDATED
goedel-db-connector   default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.sandbox-m3.1530.p1.openshiftapps.com/gratinierer-dev/goedel-db-connector   latest   2 minutes ago
```

As noted [here](https://austindewey.com/2020/10/25/you-can-use-openshifts-imagestreams-with-deployments-heres-how/) my Imagestream should be correct

```
apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: goedel-db-connector
  namespace: gratinierer-dev
  uid: 9e735a9e-3311-4fbf-8d14-cb491b5f8ee7
  resourceVersion: '1384476123'
  generation: 2
  creationTimestamp: '2023-10-10T05:47:01Z'
spec:
  lookupPolicy:
    local: true
status:
  dockerImageRepository: >-
    image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/gratinierer-dev/goedel-db-connector
  publicDockerImageRepository: >-
    default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.sandbox-m3.1530.p1.openshiftapps.com/gratinierer-dev/goedel-db-connector
  tags:
    - tag: latest
      items:
        - created: '2023-10-10T05:47:01Z'
          dockerImageReference: >-
            image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/gratinierer-dev/goedel-db-connector@sha256:44adfeb631dc0a9c23a7c44f28224ecb62294de695c61e7e8a9d8b5d21d5d5ce
          image: >-
            sha256:44adfeb631dc0a9c23a7c44f28224ecb62294de695c61e7e8a9d8b5d21d5d5ce
          generation: 1
```

from that point I would expect, that a Service/Deployment with `goedel-db-connector:latest` should work. But it fails, whatever I try:

```
spec:
  containerConcurrency: 0
  containers:
    - image: 'goedel-db-connector:latest'
      name: goedel-db-connector
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      readinessProbe:
        successThreshold: 1
        tcpSocket:
          port: 0
      resources: {}
  enableServiceLinks: false
  timeoutSeconds: 300
status:
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2023-10-10T05:48:47Z'
      message: >-
        Unable to fetch image "goedel-db-connector:latest": failed to resolve
        image to digest: HEAD
        https://index.docker.io/v2/library/goedel-db-connector/manifests/latest:
        unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized (HEAD responses have no body,
        use GET for details)
      reason: ContainerMissing
      status: 'False'
      type: ContainerHealthy
    - lastTransitionTime: '2023-10-10T05:48:47Z'
      message: >-
        Unable to fetch image "goedel-db-connector:latest": failed to resolve
        image to digest: HEAD
        https://index.docker.io/v2/library/goedel-db-connector/manifests/latest:
        unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized (HEAD responses have no body,
        use GET for details)
      reason: ContainerMissing
      status: 'False'
      type: Ready
    - lastTransitionTime: '2023-10-10T05:48:47Z'
      reason: ResolvingDigests
      status: Unknown
      type: ResourcesAvailable
  observedGeneration: 1
```

I can make it work, if I paste the full-path for image.

```
     image: >-
        default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.sandbox-m3.1530.p1.openshiftapps.com/gratinierer-dev/goedel-db-connector@sha256:44adfeb631dc0a9c23a7c44f28224ecb62294de695c61e7e8a9d8b5d21d5d5ce
```

In this case the deployment runs fine, so the image is there and ready.
but this should no be a desired solution in my eyes.

do I have a general misunderstanding of the concept?

Answer (score 0):

ImageStream is a resource for OpenShift. So if you want to use the imagestream in a Kubernetes Resource, you need to set image lookup policy*1 for your resources.

e.g.

```
$ oc set image-lookup goedel-db-connector
```

Here are some notes.

- This feature can not be used in the `default` namespace, nor in any `openshift-` or `kube-` namespace.
- The feature image lookup policy will affect only the resources that are created after the lookup policy is changed.

There are two ways to enable image lookup policy in OpenShift.
First, you can enable image lookup policy for a image stream. It means, all resources can reference the imagestream.

```
$ oc set image-lookup goedel-db-connector
```

Second, you can enable image lookup policy for a specific resource like a deployment. It means, only the resource can refer image streams.

```
$ oc set image-lookup delploy/your-deployment-name
```

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/openshift_images/using-imagestreams-with-kube-resources.html

Comment: as you can see in my post look-up-policy should already be correct: ```spec:
  lookupPolicy:
    local: true```. 
so your hint does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ah. ok I missed that.

Comment: @gratinierer Have you changed the lookup policy in your imagestream after you deployed your deployment?
In my local environment, When I changed the lookup policy in my imagestream, it didn't work for existing a deployment resource. However, it worked after re-create the deployment.

Comment: thanks you, but still the same, even with a simple:
`kn service create new-sl --image goedel-db-connector:latest` I get an error `Error: RevisionFailed: Revision "new-sl-00001" failed with message: Unable to fetch image "goedel-db-connector:latest": failed to resolve image to digest: HEAD https://index.docker.io/v2/library/goedel-db-connector/manifests/latest: unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized (HEAD responses have no body, use GET for details).
Run 'kn --help' for usage

Comment: @gratinierer ok, you may need to link secret to the default service account in your namespace.  First, create secret with the command `oc create secret docker-registry <pull_secret_name> --docker-server=<registry_server> --docker-username=<user_name> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<email>`. Then, Link it to the service account `oc secrets link default <pull_secret_name> --for=pull`

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-from-secure-registries_using-image-pull-secrets

Comment: thanks again. The point is: I don't want to pull anything docker. I want to pull from the poenshift-internal private registry via ImageStreamTag. 
It should not be necessary to configure anything in this case. As mentioned: if I paste the complete path to the image it works fine without any password or something else.

Comment: @gratinierer Is your imagestream in the same namespace which the deployment is stored?

Comment: yes it is, I just got one namespace.

Comment: ok, I thought if the imagestream and deployment are stored in different namespaces, openshift may try to search image in dockerhub.

Comment: I believe the kn command is designed for native Kubernetes operations and does not provide an interface to specify ImageStreams. If you're deploying an application using Deployment, creating the Deployment with the desired configurations is a better approach to address the issue.